# Sort an array of elements in ascending order by number of occurences

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Having an array like this: `[4, 2, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4]`

there are one occurences of 1, 5, 6
two occurences of 4
three occurences of 2

First, there must be added in ascending order the elements with one occurence: `1, 5, 6`

After that, the elements with two occurences: `1, 5, 6, 4, 4`

and the elements with three occurences: `1, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2`

I've tried to sort the array and then to move the elements with more occurences to the end of the array but it's not very efficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could count frequencies using array `Array.prototype.reduce` method and then sort it by occurrence in ascending order.

```js
let arr = [4, 2, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4];

arr = Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    p[c] = p[c] ?? 0;
    p[c] += 1;
    return p;
  }, {})
)
  .sort((x, y) => x[1] - y[1])
  .flatMap(([x, y]) => Array(y).fill(+x));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: it wasn't me who did it

Answer (score 1):

First you need to count the occurrences of each number in the array, we'll use a `reduce` for this like so:

```
let count = arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This will result in an object where the keys are the numbers and the values are their number of occurrences in the array `arr`.

Then we'll just sort the items by that count first then by the numbers themselves:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => (count[a] - count[b]) || (a - b));
```

`(count[a] - count[b]) || (a - b)` is using a short circuit evaluation, which results in a sort by count/number of occurrences in ascending order, then by the numbers themselves if `count[a] - count[b] === 0` (meaning that the numbers `a` and `b` have the same count).

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = [4, 2, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4];

let count = arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

arr.sort((a, b) => (count[a] - count[b]) || (a - b));

console.log("[ " + arr.join(", ") + " ]");
```